# Problem autoexecuting yuicompressor in Vim (executing it from any directory)

Tags: vim, yui-compressor

I made yuicompressor work from the command line.

But the only thing I didn't understand from [this tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_execute_yuicompressor) is this part:

```
You most install yuicompressor and make yuicompressor executable from any directory.
```

**How do I make it execute from any directory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [put it in your PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) environment variable in Windows or in similar one in other OS'es.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it didn't work! I put 'D:\yuicompressor-2.42\build' in Path but when i tried executing it the commandline displayed: unable to access jarfile. The same message when I wrote an incorrect directory.

Comment: You need to logout-login in or reboot in order to let OS load new values into path variable, have you tried that?